# Display Tag use in Liferay 5.2.3

Tags: java, struts, liferay, displaytag

I am using display tag for pagination in my table in Liferay 5.2.3. My code snippet is:

```
<logic:notEmpty name="ReportList"> 
                            <div class="TabbedPanelsContent">
                            <div id="LoanPosition_Tabel">                           
                           <display:table   name="sessionScope.ReportList" requestURI="${urlRepDetails}" pagesize='<%= pagesize %>' sort="list" class="displaytag" defaultsort="3" defaultorder="ascending"  >
                                <display:column href="${urlReverseStatusRepDetails}"paramId="fileNumber" paramProperty="fileNumber" property="fileNumber" title= '<%= messages.getMessage("sr.fileNumber") %>' sortable="true" headerClass="sortable" class="tabel-border" />
                                <display:column property="uploadFileName" title='<%= messages.getMessage("sr.uploadFileName") %>' sortable="true" headerClass="sortable" class="tabel-border"/>
                                <display:column property="product" title='<%= messages.getMessage("sr.product") %>'sortable="true" headerClass="sortable" class="tabel-border"/>
                                <display:column property="uploadDate" title='<%= messages.getMessage("sr.uploadDate") %>' sortable="true" headerClass="sortable" class="tabel-border-rt" style="text-align:right"/>
                                <display:column property="uploadTime" title='<%= messages.getMessage("sr.uploadTime") %>'sortable="true" headerClass="sortable" class="tabel-border"/>
                                <display:column property="totalInvoiceAmount" title='<%= messages.getMessage("sr.totalInvoiceAmount") %>' sortable="true" headerClass="sortable" class="tabel-border"/>
                                <display:column property="totalNumbarOfInvoice" title='<%= messages.getMessage("sr.totalNumbarOfInvoice") %>' sortable="true" headerClass="sortable" class="tabel-border-rt" style="text-align:right"/>
                                <display:column property="totalSuccessfulCases" title='<%= messages.getMessage("sr.totalSuccessfulCases") %>' sortable="true" headerClass="sortable" class="tabel-border"/>
                                <display:column property="amountDisbursed" title='<%= messages.getMessage("sr.amountDisbursed") %>' sortable="true" headerClass="sortable" class="tabel-border"/>
                                <display:column property="fileDescription" title='<%= messages.getMessage("sr.fileDescription") %>' sortable="true" headerClass="sortable" class="tabel-border"/>
                                <display:column property="manufacrCompCode" title='<%= messages.getMessage("sr.manufacrCompCode") %>' sortable="true" headerClass="sortable" class="tabel-border"/>
                                <display:column property="status" title='<%= messages.getMessage("sr.status") %>'sortable="true" headerClass="sortable" class="tabel-border"/>                  
                                <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.placement" value="bottom" />
                                <display:setProperty name="basic.empty.showtable" value="true" />
                                <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.onepage" value='' />
                                <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.no_items_found" value='' />
                                <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.one_item_found" value='' />
                                <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.all_items_found" value='' />
                                <display:setProperty name="paging.banner.some_items_found" value='' />
                            </display:table>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                </logic:notEmpty>
```

Issue is when i am clicking on the file number i am downloading a file but when i move to the next page i.e. Page no 2 and subsequent pages, the file which i downloaded last time again gets downloaded with simply clicking on the pagination . 
What happening here is the last clicked request number gain gets posted from the form on clicking page 2 or 3. I am not able to differentiate between click of request number and pagination links. How to resolve this?
I am struts framework in Liferay 5.2.3.

Comment: @MaverickI understand that when you click page button also your 'download file button' event is triggered. You said that 'when i am clicking on the file number i am downloading a file' where you catch this event and how you post the data.

Comment: @erhun: as you can see i have this: <display:column href="${urlTmlReverseStatusRepDetails}"  Here on clicking i am calling liferay-portlet:renderURL. Code is      <liferay-portlet:renderURL var="urlTmlStatusRepDetails">
  <liferay-portlet:param name="_spage" value="/customersummaryaction.do" />
  <liferay-portlet:param name="trans_tab_sel" value="tmlStatusRepDetails" />
</liferay-portlet:renderURL> Here i am passing the values as HTTP Request parameters and in my method in action class what i am doing is   request.getParameter("fileNumber")

Comment: I need to know how to get this request number as null after first call  or differentiate between clicking the request number and pagination links

Comment: i cannot see how you handle paging click, can you post the code how to handle paging.

Comment: @erhun I am using display-tag jar to paginate

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the pagination link, it calls every javascript function preset in the same jsp or the javascript that has been included in the same jsp.